# Path inside the dictionary from the variable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variables

I have a code:

```
def replaceJSONFilesList(JSONFilePath, JSONsDataPath, newJSONData):
    JSONFileHandleOpen = open(JSONFilePath, 'r')
    ReadedJSONObjects = json.load(JSONFileHandleOpen)
    JSONFileHandleOpen.close()
    ReadedJSONObjectsModifyingSector = ReadedJSONObjects[JSONsDataPath]
    for newData in newJSONData:
        ReadedJSONObjectsModifyingSector.append(newData)
    JSONFileHandleWrite = open(JSONFilePath, 'w')
    json.dump(ReadedJSONObjects, JSONFileHandleWrite)
    JSONFileHandleWrite.close()

def modifyJSONFile(Path):
    JSONFilePath = '/path/file'
    JSONsDataPath = "['first']['second']"
    newJSONData = 'somedata'
    replaceJSONFilesList(JSONFilePath, JSONsDataPath, newJSONData)
```

Now I have an error:

```
KeyError: "['first']['second']"
```

But if I try:

```
ReadedJSONObjectsModifyingSector = ReadedJSONObjects['first']['second']
```

Everything is okay.

How I should send the path to the list from the JSON's dictionary — from one function to other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot pass language syntax elements as if they were data strings.  Similarly, you could not pass the string "2 > 1 and False", and expect the function to be able to insert that into an `if` condition.

Instead, extract the data items and pass them as separate strings (which matches their syntax in the calling routine), or as a tuple of strings.  For instance:

```
JSONsDataPath = ('first', 'second')
...
```

Then, inside the function ...

```
ReadedJSONObjects[JSONsDataPath[0]][JSONsDataPath[1]]
```

If you have a variable sequence of indices, then you need to write code to handle that case; research that on Stack Overflow.

The iterative way to handle an unknown quantity of indices is like this:

```
obj = ReadedJSONObjects
for index in JSONsDataPath:
    obj = obj[index]
```

Comment: Thanks you! Excuse me, how I may create universal function "replaceJSONFilesList" to have support for N values of "JSONsDataPath"? not only 2.

Comment: Again, research that on SO.  You need to either "explode" the list, or iterate through it.  I added the iteration method to my answer.